# CSS animation of SVG elements not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, svg

I'm creating a set of SVG icons and I'd like to animate some of the elements using CSS. The example code works in IE, Firefox and S̵a̵f̵a̵r̵i̵ but refuses to animate in Chrome. If I move the animation class from the `circle` to the `use` element Chrome will animate the whole icon but this is not the effect I need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<style> 
.drop {
  animation: dropFrames linear 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes dropFrames{
  0% { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
</style>

<svg style="display:none" >
    <defs>
    
    <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey"/>
        <circle cx="50" cy="150" r="20"  fill="blue" class="drop"/>
    </symbol>

    </defs>
</svg>

<svg ><use xlink:href="#icon" /></svg>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried this with the `-webkit-` prefix but it didn't help.

**Edit:** This example no longer works in Safari

Comment: So 8 years later and I'm back having very similar problems. The above example now works in Chrome which is a plus but I still get problems trying to use the SVG <animation> tag in Chrome. It turns out that the style="display:none" was probably the root cause of the problem as replacing it width='0' height='0' cures the animation problems I was having in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't access the inner parts of a `<use>` element with CSS.

An alternative it to break the 'icon' into separate symbols and then combined two `use` elements into a single SVG.

```css
.drop {
  animation: dropFrames linear 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes dropFrames {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none">
  <defs>

    <symbol id="icon-top" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon-bottom" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <circle cx="50" cy="150" r="20" fill="blue" />
    </symbol>

  </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#icon-top" />
  <use xlink:href="#icon-bottom" class="drop" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Is this an SVG limitation or Chrome? It's frustrating that I'm able to animate the elements of the `<use>` in FireFox, IE and Safari but not Chrome.

Comment: My understanding is that this is an SVG limitation...but it's possible that my information is out of date or as you say it may be a bug in Chrome...or they haven't cahught up yet.

Comment: This should work, all use instances should animate. `<use>` has bugs on most UAs though.